# Placing two gridviews on top of each other

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to have two gridviews on top of each other like so:[image]

The top one has style float:right and overflow: auto for a scroll bar.

The bottom one has style overflow: auto for a scroll bar as well.

However, when I try to view my page, gridview 2 ends up to the left of gridview 1 (unless I remove overflow: auto). Is there a way to fix that? I tried using `<br>` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<div>` element between the two gridviews with `style="clear: both;"` which will act as a break between the floating elements.

***OR*** you could just add `style="clear: both;"` to each gridview.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.. As @Mike suggested add Clear:both for both the div..

Or place the Two grids entirely in different div..

As the div is a block level element they will fall one below another..